# Python GAE datastore datetime query.filter by day

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime, timezone, google-cloud-datastore

**Python Google App Engine (GAE)**

In the datastore I have stored datetime on entries, which is in UTC (Expected behavior).

The issue is when using a query.filter to grab a specific day in another time zone.

Example GAE datastore datetime entries (UTC):

- 2014-11-4 11pm UTC
- 2014-11-4 12pm UTC
- 2014-11-4 01am UTC

Simple enough to pull those entries by date using UTC:

```
query_date = datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
query.filter('DateTimeUTC >=', query_date)
query.filter('DateTimeUTC <', query_date+timedelta(days=1))
```

Or like this:

```
start_date = datetime.strptime('11/04/2014', '%m/%d/%Y')
end_date = datetime.strptime('11/05/2014', '%m/%d/%Y')
query.filter('DateTimeUTC >=', start_date)
query.filter('DateTimeUTC <', end_date)
```

However, let's consider the fact that although those three entries were entered on 11/04/2014 in accordance with UTC, the original user was in PST, thus making that third entry actually on 11/03/2014, not on the 4th (1am UTC = previous day 5pm PST).

So using this example code and data, let's imagine a much bigger set of data, all entered by users in PST, EST, etc. and now you're trying to pull specific days for each of them (let's focus on PST to stay consistent - UTC-8).

How can you query.filter for days in a specific time zone instead of using UTC's definition of days?

Again, try sticking to PST so we're all on the same page.

I'm trying to keep things simple and clean using this format, but if my style of code on GAE is slow performance-wise or there is a better route (proven by speed compared to this) then I'm all for it.

Comment: I know it would be a pain to update existing entities but why not store the datetimes as PST instead of UTC? Or when you build your start/end dates shift them by 8 to be PST?

Comment: That does not work when you have a global application that has multiple people in different time zones (PST, EST, etc.) does that make sense?

Comment: It does, When doing the searches are they based always from PST or from where ever the people are?

If its local time then when you do your filter simply subtract the timezone from the times.

Comment: GAE only stores in UTC, so by storing on their servers in PST by doing a conversion you would then run into a problem converting back as the PST time stored in a UTC environment would be incorrect when you say then convert to EST.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the start and end time of your local day into UTC and then query between those UTC times.